# jQuery Ajax call, error function is call but success is not call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```
function processAjaxCalls(url,data,onsuccessCallBack,onerrorCallBack,dataType,requestId,hideProcessing){    
    if(requestId != null &&requestId != undefined &&requestId.length > 0 && requestId != "")
    {

        if( ajaxRequests[ requestId ] )
            ajaxRequests[ requestId ].abort();
    }   
    alert("1");
    if(hideProcessing!=true)
        show_winMask(1);
    var reqObj = jQuery.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: url,
           dataType: (dataType != null && dataType != undefined && dataType.length > 0)? dataType :  "json",
           data:data,
           success: function(result)
           {
               alert("process SUCCESS RESULT"+result);
               if( ajaxRequests[ requestId ] )
                  delete ajaxRequests[ requestId ];
              if(hideProcessing!=true)  
                  show_winMask(0);
              if( result != null && result.sExpires){
                   loadFormSessionTimeOut(result);
              }
              //eval( '('+onsuccessCallBack +'(result) )' );
              alert("bfefore var args");
              var args = [result];
              dynamicFunctionCall(onsuccessCallBack, args);

           },

           error:function(status)
           {

               alert("process STATUS ERROR"+status);
               if( status.statusText != "abort"){
                   if( ajaxRequests[ requestId ] )
                      delete ajaxRequests[ requestId ];
                   if(hideProcessing!=true)
                       show_winMask(0);
                   eval( '('+onerrorCallBack +'(status) )' );
              }

               if( status != null && status.sExpires){
                   loadFormSessionTimeOut(status);
               } 
           }

    }); 


    if( requestId != null && requestId != undefined && requestId.length > 0 && requestId != "")
        ajaxRequests[ requestId ] = reqObj;

}
```

Error Function is working but success is not working.. How i rectified??

Comment: Check the URL you are calling. In error function add these two (jqXHR, status, errorThrown). What does it says now in your alert?

Comment: ok. How i rectified this one? BECAUSE ERROR is working. Inside of a Error function alert is coming. but Success is not working/

Comment: #besciualex: Inside of Error one alert is here. that only Showed.

Comment: Please read carefully. I said:    " in error function replace function(status) with function(jqXHR, status, errorThrown). What does it says now in your alert?" I need you to do this because one problem it might be the URL you are calling. I need to find out the response code you are getting from error function.

Comment: it means your ajax request returns an error. most likely an issue on your server. Force your server to return a status 200 maybe?

Comment: ok. Please send the code #besciualex & #xshirase

Comment: @besciualex i am given like this:
  error:function(jqXHR, status, errorThrown)
     {
 alert("process STATUS ERROR"+status);
      alert("process STATUS ERROR"+jqXHR);
      alert("process STATUS ERROR"+errorThrown);

in screen alert showed like follow:

process STATUS ERRORparsererror
process STATUS ERROR[object Object]
process STATUS ERRORSyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

Comment: @EdwinBenjamin . Ok. Now execute the code. You receive tree error alerts. What do they say? It is pretty important in order to debug and fix your error.

Comment: @besciualex : How to fix this Error? Please give the Clear Solution? change the code and give to me.

Comment: @EdwinBenjamin In order to solve a problem you need to know what causes it. That's what I was trying to obtain from you. Please learn English, before asking for help in it.

Answer (score 0):

"Success is not working" problem happens for two usual reason. First check the server script that you are calling is returning proper value. and second the the url and the data you are sending from the client. That's all it need to make a success call in ajax

Comment: @yah! Nitin. How to make that one in Success? that's Solution only i required?

Comment: Your client side is looking right, if you have provided the right url value then it will go to the server for request. check console->network there will the name of url on which you are sending the data. check if the data is not coming then it will show error of server side script. If there is an error then fix it and you will get your data. Or if in  Console ->Network you do not find your url then your url is empty.

Comment: then click on it and check that if your server side has send any data , if it has, then you got the data you want. if it didn't then it will show the mistake that you have done on server side. Basically that's why there is Console, to check ajax call.